# adb.exe causing problems with build and run for Android in Unity

Tags: java, unity-game-engine, error-handling, android-sdk-2.3

Error building Player:

```
Win32Exception: ApplicationName='C:/Users/K's User/AppData/Local/Android/android-sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe', CommandLine='devices', CurrentDirectory='C:/Users/Kelly's User/AppData/Local/Android/android-sdk'
```

What's the problem here? This is only when I use build and run. When only using build, this is the error:

```
Error building Player: Win32Exception: ApplicationName='C:\Users\K's User\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\build-tools\23.0.1\aapt.exe', CommandLine='package --auto-add-overlay -v -f -m -J gen -M AndroidManifest.xml -S "res" -I "C:/Users/K's User/AppData/Local/Android/android-sdk\platforms\android-23\android.jar" -F bin/resources.ap_', CurrentDirectory='Temp/StagingArea'
```

For what I've already tried, please see my previous question :) I've had this trouble for days now.

[Error Building Player - Win32 Exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32922619/error-building-player-win32-exception)

I'm using `Unity 5.2`, `Windows 8` and have the latest `Android SDK (23.0.1)` Thanks for your help in advance this is driving me mad.

Comment: Have you tried to use another folder without the ' in the name? (ie; "K's User"), maybe its not related, but your param starts with a '. Or you can try to scape that char with \'. Or try to use " ie,  ApplicationName="C:\Users\......."

Comment: I haven't tried that, this was the default location that SDK was sent to when installed. Would the ' mean the path couldn't be followed?

Comment: Mmmm What about http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/978703/error-building-android-player-win32-exception.html

Comment: I though that maybe the ' could be the cause of some kind of problem, but I think that all the windows users have the same pattern on their user directory path.

Comment: I've moved the sdk to C:\Android\android-sdk - a much simpler path and it works perfect! Thanks for this advice, I guess we can assume it was the ' ?? hard to say I suppose but a good call. I guess when setting up a PC in the future I wont include ' in user names. Thanks again!